# Identify which button was pressed from HTML in WSGI-Python (without any framework like flask and Django)?

Tags: html, python-3.x, wsgi

I  am implementing web-application in core python using WSGI, python3, and apache2. Now I need to detect which button was pressed based on some value or id of a button in python WSGI file
Please suggest the code which I can place in the WSGI file.

Python Code:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
    post_env = environ.copy()
    post_env['QUERY_STRING'] = ''
    post = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=environ['wsgi.input'],
        environ=post_env,
        keep_blank_values=True
    )
    html =  page_header + content + page_footer
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
return [html.encode('utf-8')]
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div> 
    <form method="post">
        <button id="button1">Button1</button>
        <input type="text"></input> Status 
        <button id="button2">Button2</button>
        <input type="text"></input> Status2
    </form>
</div>
```

I expected the code something life

if "button1":
    "Some code"
if "button2":
    "some code"

Answer (score 0):

I have used AJAX to send data from HTML to WSGI

HTML CODE:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://link/sample/",
    data: {'param1':"Generate",'param2':htmlTDES},
    success: function (html)
    {alert("AJAX PASS");},
    error: function(request, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
    {
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

WSGI CODE:

```
if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
    post_env = environ.copy()
    post_env['QUERY_STRING'] = ''
    post = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=environ['wsgi.input'],
        environ=post_env,
        keep_blank_values=True
    )
    name = post.getvalue('param1')
    htmlTDES = post.getvalue('param2')
    if name=="Generate":
        Genrate_function()
    html =  page_header + content + page_footer
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')]
return [output.encode('utf-8')]
```